# web.config URL rewrite not rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-config

I've been having a problem recently with one of my rewrite rules in web.config. It's giving me a 500 error, yet it used to work in the past. I have, however, recently had to change it over from .htaccess to web.config, so I feel that may be part of the problem, but it used to work even after changing it over so I don't know what the problem is?

The web.config is currently sat as just imported rules now (default after importing now) and the content is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^images/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.)(jpg|png|gif)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="images/old/{R:1}{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^images/thumbs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.)(jpg|png|gif)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="images/old/{R:1}th.{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^api$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 4" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^images/(\w*\.)(jpg|png|gif)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="images/old/{R:1}{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 5" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^images/thumbs/(\w*\.)(jpg|png|gif)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="images/old/{R:1}th.{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 6" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.([a-z]{1,4})$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm not the best at web.config, so if you know any reason as to why it may not be working after importing, can you help out? Thanks very much!